# Classifying as Empirical or Classical

Tags: statistics

I need to identify two questions as either Empirical or Classical Probability. The questions are as follows:
1. The probability of choosing 6 numbers from 1 to 40 that match the 6 numbers drawn by a state lottery is 1/3,838,380=0.00000026
2. According to a survey, the probability that a voting age citizen chosen at random is in favor of a skateboarding ban is about 0.63

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What do you understand about the definitions of the two kinds of probability? What are your thoughts about the question?

Comment: I know that Empirical probability means to have a final number on observed results, and Classical Probability is getting a result based on random selection

Comment: Which of those examples has "observed results"? Which is a reliably "random" process (choosing from well defined equally likely cases)?

Comment: The first question has observed results, and the second question has a random process

Comment: I think that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to stackexchange.  You can answer your own question here if you like. That way people who visit will know it's taken care of.